# How can these two functions be consolidated into one function?

Tags: function, visual-c++, mfc, c++20

Here are two very similar event handlers for two list boxes:

```
void CCreateReportDlg::OnLbnSelchangeListOclmAssignments()
{
    const auto iAssignmentIndex = m_lbAssignmentsOCLM.GetCurSel();

    // Reset selected items
    auto const iSelCount{ m_lbNotAvailable.GetSelCount() };
    if (iSelCount > 0)
    {
        std::vector<int> listSelItems(iSelCount);
        m_lbNotAvailable.GetSelItems(gsl::narrow<int>(listSelItems.size()), listSelItems.data());

        for (auto const index : listSelItems)
        {
            m_lbNotAvailable.SetSel(index, false);
        }
    }

    if (m_lbAssignmentsOCLM.GetCheck(iAssignmentIndex) == BST_CHECKED)
    {
        const auto eAssignType = 
            static_cast<MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType>(m_lbAssignmentsOCLM.GetItemData(iAssignmentIndex));
        const auto datMeeting = GetMeetingDate(m_iLastGridRow);

        CStringArray aryStrBrothers;
        theApp.MSAToolsInterface().GetPersonnelForMeeting(
            datMeeting,
            theApp.GetAssignHistoryPathEx(),
            eAssignType,
            aryStrBrothers);

        for (int iNameIndex = 0; iNameIndex < aryStrBrothers.GetSize(); iNameIndex++)
        {
            const auto iLocatedIndex = m_lbNotAvailable.FindStringExact(-1, aryStrBrothers[iNameIndex]);
            if (iLocatedIndex != LB_ERR)
            {
                m_lbNotAvailable.SetSel(iLocatedIndex);
            }
        }
    }
}

void CCreateReportDlg::OnLbnSelchangeListWeekendAssignments()
{
    const auto iAssignmentIndex = m_lbAssignmentsWeekend.GetCurSel();

    // Reset selected items
    auto const iSelCount{ m_lbNotAvailable.GetSelCount() };
    if (iSelCount > 0)
    {
        std::vector<int> listSelItems(iSelCount);
        m_lbNotAvailable.GetSelItems(gsl::narrow<int>(listSelItems.size()), listSelItems.data());

        for (auto const index : listSelItems)
        {
            m_lbNotAvailable.SetSel(index, false);
        }
    }

    if (m_lbAssignmentsWeekend.GetCheck(iAssignmentIndex) == BST_CHECKED)
    {
        const auto eAssignType =
            static_cast<MSAToolsLibrary::WeekendAssignmentType>(m_lbAssignmentsWeekend.GetItemData(iAssignmentIndex));
        const auto datMeeting = GetMeetingDate(m_iLastGridRow);

        CStringArray aryStrBrothers;
        theApp.MSAToolsInterface().GetPersonnelForMeeting(
            datMeeting,
            theApp.GetAssignHistoryPathEx(),
            eAssignType,
            aryStrBrothers);

        for (int iNameIndex = 0; iNameIndex < aryStrBrothers.GetSize(); iNameIndex++)
        {
            const auto iLocatedIndex = m_lbNotAvailable.FindStringExact(-1, aryStrBrothers[iNameIndex]);
            if (iLocatedIndex != LB_ERR)
            {
                m_lbNotAvailable.SetSel(iLocatedIndex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

They are pretty much identical, apart from:

- Listbox: `m_lbAssignmentsOCLM` / `m_lbAssignmentsWeekend`
- Flag cast: `static_cast<MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType>` / `static_cast<MSAToolsLibrary::WeekendAssignmentType>`

The `GetPersonnelForMeeting` function is overloaded to accept both flag types. Initially I was going to write a common function that accepted the list box as a referenced parameter. But then I came a cropper on the static cast.

So how can I write a single method that both of my handlers can call that allows for the two issues raised?

Comment: By making the common implementation into a template?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I've used templates a handler of times but they usually affected the parameters passed to the template as opposed to the static cast I am trying to do within the body of the function. Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: `template <typename AssnType> void HandleListboxChange(const CListBox& lb) { ... auto assn_type = static_cast<AssnType>(lb.GetItemData(iAssignmentIndex)); ...}` You call it as e.g. `HandleListboxChange<MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType>(m_lbAssignmentsOCLM)`

Comment: Without even opening VS, copied the two functions into two Notepad instances, and by pressing Alt+Tab, I found that the only difference is the listbox control. Therefore an easy solution would be to move the code into a new function with a listbox control (ref or ptr), as an arg, and call the function from each handler. And this because the message-map doesn't pass any parameter to the handler. You can also experiment with the message map, eg use the `ON_NOTIFY` macro instead and pass the control ID to the handler -requires manually editing the message-map and the Wizard may not work very well

Comment: To overcome the two different types issue (`MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType` / `MSAToolsLibrary::WeekendAssignmentType`) a better solution might be use some kind of virtualization instead of this casting in the higher-level code, if these have a common ancestor. Or the `GetPersonnelForMeeting()` function be template-d. In any case there are two different types and two functions actually.

Comment: Here are the differences: https://i.imgur.com/jI4ZfN6.png .So what's different is: 1. the variable of the listbox, which I think you can make a way into passing its ID via the message map. This is the easy part. 2. The cast on `eAssignType` is to other type. Here it's more contrived. You can: a) do a switch-case based on what list you are handling. b) If `WeekendAssignmentType` and `AssignmentType` are on the same hierarchy — by their names I suspect they are — you can have a factory method returning the right instance. c) Act on it using templates. If I could, I would follow with approach b).